# How did King Ozymandias's statue crumble?

Tags: engineering, architecture

I was thinking about [Ozymandias](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46565/ozymandias), and it struck me as a little weird that the head of the statue fell so close to the legs while the rest of the statue seemingly disintegrated into sand. Thinking a bit further about this led to a prompt which I hope the worldbuilders here will find amusing.

> You have been tasked with King Ozymandias to build a great statue. However, you believe that Ozymandias's legacy would be *much better* represented by two vast and trunkless legs of stone and a shattered visage, surrounded by lone and level sands.

Design a statue to the following constraints:

- The statue must stand for the rest of King Ozymandias's lifetime (around 50 years)
- At some point afterward, within the next thousand years, it must collapse such that it meets the description in the poem.

  - The lower legs must remain standing.
  - The head must fall next to the legs.
  - The plaque must remain readable.
  - The rest of the statue - torso, arms, and any ornamentation like scepters or swords - must be destroyed or otherwise rendered invisible from the surface.
  - The statue must be surrounded on all sides by empty desert.

If you can accomplish that:

- Keep obvious sabotage to a minimum. King Ozymandias has given you an unlimited budget, but if you stuff the torso of the statue with gunpowder, the amount of bribes you have to pay to keep the workers quiet could attract scrutiny on audit.
- Use as old a technology base as possible. King Ozymandias distrusts the new stuff - especially that stuff that those time travelers from 2020 are selling.
- Avoid external interaction after the statue's completion. The statue won't crumble until after the end of your lifetime, so if you pay people to demolish the statue afterward, you have no way of ensuring that they'll actually come through for you.
- Be as certain as you can of the primary objectives.

Comment: Data point: The poem is based on a statue brought to England by (afair) the British Museum.  The poem was a competition bewteen the poet and a friend. The other poem is not as good (by their judgement then and mine now :-) ). Available online.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stone or bronze for the legs and head, and a gold armo(u)r covering his torso - make the armo(u)r a structural, weight bearing element. During the king's lifetime, nobody dares touch the statue, but you can be sure it will be looted sooner or later. Probably sooner.

Comment: One anecdote that is less than amusing was post-Katrina New Orleans, looters were ripping out the copper piping from abandoned properties, and blighted schools for example, which had extensive plumbing with high number of bathrooms, and showers, and pool facilities, were a valued target.

Comment: I like the social engineering approach. However, if the thieves use cables to pull the statue down, the head will land a full statue-height away from the feet, which isn't quite the effect of the poem. Can this approach be modified to guarantee that the head falls near the feet?

Comment: If the attachment between the head and torso was weak, but not obviously so, theives would likely attach a rope to the head to pull down the statue, but only bring down the head. They'd then pull somewhere else for the torso.

Comment: +1 for taking into account human foibles. I'd recommend settling on stone for the head and legs, as we know those weren't looted. You might consider leaving some random pieces of nice worked stone nearby just to satisfy the immediate needs of the gold  diggers and perhaps stave off future stone looters.

Answer (score 8):

[Calcite alabaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabaster#Calcite_alabaster) for feet and head. [Gypsum alabaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabaster#Ancient_and_Classical_Near_East) for the trunk and hands.

If you want a faster decay for the trunk, dig a cylindrical cavity in the trunk and fill it with [soda ash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_carbonate#Mining), the slow reaction is

> Na<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub> + CaSO<sub>4</sub> -> CaCO<sub>3</sub> + Na<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>

with the water coming from the gypsum crystallization. It will slowly let behind a porous weak limestone as the "rot" progresses.
Make the trunk hole for the soda ash eccentric, closer to the chest, to increase the chances the head will fall in front of the statue.
Make the pedestal low and the plaque from marble.

All the materials can be sourced from the trading sphere of ancient (and mythical) Greece and were used for statues and bas-reliefs of the time. Desert climate will compensate for the softness of the stone and water erosion, but one will need to protect the statue from desert storms.

Comment: As for why the statue is made of two different materials in the first place: supply problems and time pressure.

Comment: Now... any plausible explanation for the soda ash when the king inevitably asks?

Comment: @JohnDvorak Have you seen many times King Ozymandias examining the inside of the statues? No? Then it's not quite inevitable, is it? Besides, King Ozymandias is not a graduate with a major in chemistry - were it to be so, he'd rather be an alchemist than a king - so any plausible bogus explanation will likely do.